# How to use a binarysearch on a sorted array to find the number of integers within a certain range. (with duplicates)

Tags: java, search, binary-search

Say you have a sorted array of integers:

```
{3,4,4,6,10,15,15,19,23,23,24,30}
```

And you want to find the number of integers that fall within a range of 4 and 23.

```
{4,4,6,10,15,15,19,23,23}
```

Thus the result would be 9.

I wrote a binarysearch implementation, but I'm not sure how I would modify it to also take into account the fact that there can be multiple integers that match the upper bounds of the range.

I thought of adding a boolean in the method signature to ask whether to look for the upper bounds of the key, but I'm not sure if it can be done in a single method while keeping O(log(N)) complexity.

Or is there some other way of finding the # of items in that range in the sorted array in O(log(N)) time?

This is what I have so far:

```
int start = rangeBinarySearch(arr, 4, false);
int end = rangeBinarySearch(arr, 23, true); // true would indicate that I want the position of the last occurrence of the key.

int totalInRange = (Math.abs(end) - Math.abs(start) -1)


private static int rangeBinarySearch(int[] items, int key, boolean lastIndex) {
    if(items == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    int start = 0;
    int end = items.length - 1;

    while(start <= end) {
        int mIndex = (start + end) / 2;
        int middle = items[mIndex];

        if(middle < key)
            start = (mIndex +1);
        else if(middle > key)
            end = (mIndex -1);
        else
            return mIndex; // Possible something here to find the upper bounds?
    }

    return -(start +1);
}
```

Comment: imho, do two separate method, one for finding upper boundry and second to find bottom boundry and that should be fine

Answer (score 3):

Range binary search for the lower bound and the upper bound are **different**. Here **different** means they have different stopping criteria and return step.

1. **For the lower bound (left range)**, you can call the following function to get the index in the sorted array where the value is larger or equal than it, -1 otherwise.

   ```
   int binarySearchForLeftRange(int a[], int length, int left_range)
   {
       if (a[length-1] < left_range)
           return -1;

       int low = 0;
       int high = length-1;

       while (low<=high)
       {
           int mid = low+((high-low)/2);

           if(a[mid] >= left_range)
               high = mid-1;
           else //if(a[mid]<i)
               low = mid+1;
       }

       return high+1;
   }
   ```
2. **For the upper bound (right range)**, you can call the following function to get the index in the sorted array where the value is smaller or equal than it, -1 otherwise.

   ```
   int binarySearchForRightRange(int a[], int length, int right_range)
   {
       if (a[0] > right_range)
           return -1;

       int low = 0;
       int high = length-1;

       while (low<=high)
       {
           int mid = low+((high-low)/2);

           if(a[mid] > right_range)
               high = mid-1;
           else //if(a[mid]<i)
               low = mid+1;
       }

       return low-1;
   }
   ```
3. **Finally**, if you want to get the number of how many elements within this range, it's easy based on return values of these two above functions.

   ```
   int index_left = binarySearchForLeftRange(a, length, left_range);
   int index_right = binarySearchForRightRange(a, length, right_range);

   if (index_left==-1 || index_right==-1 || index_left>index_right)
       count = 0;
   else
       count = index_right-index_left+1;
   ```

---

**Test**: (with duplicates)

```
    int a[] = {3,4,4,6,10,15,15,19,23,23,24,30};
    int length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    int left_range = 4;
    int right_range = 23;
    int index_left = binarySearchForLeftRange(a, length, left_range); // will be 1
    int index_right = binarySearchForRightRange(a, length, right_range); // will be 9

    int count; // will be 9
    if (index_left==-1 || index_right==-1 || index_left>index_right)
        count = 0;
    else
        count = index_right-index_left+1;
```

---

**EDIT**: Of course, you can merge the first two functions into one by passing one extra flag to indicate it as lower bound or upper bound, though it will be much more clear if not. Your choice!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not learning the algorithm use standart functions instead:

```
    Arrays.binarySearch
```

You basicly need first occurence of your first element (4) and last occurence of last (23) and substract. But there is no need for (4) to be there, so read documentation of Arrays.binarySearch, it gives you where (4) would be.

If you are expecting lots of (4)s you have to write your own binSearch, that returns both first and last index:

find first occurence at index i
if there is previous one look at i/2, if there is (4) look at i/4 else look at 3*i/4
...

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform two binary searches to find the lowest index before the rangeLow and the highestIndex after rangeHigh, that way you can count duplicates within the range.

This would give a time complexity of o(2 log n) as we perform the binary search twice.

```
private int searchArrayForNumbersInRange(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
    int leftIndex = searchLeft(arr, start);
    int rightIndex = searchRight(arr, end);
    int count;

    if (leftIndex < 0 || rightIndex < 0)
        return -1;
    if (rightIndex == leftIndex)
        count = 1;
    else {
        count = rightIndex - leftIndex;
    }
    return count;
}

private int searchLeft(int[] arr, int start) {
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = arr.length - 1;

    while (lo <= hi) {
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;

        if (arr[mid] == start && arr[mid -1] < start) {
            return mid - 1;
        }

        if (arr[mid] >= start)
            hi = mid - 1;
        else
            lo = mid + 1;
    }

    return -1;
}

private int searchRight(int[] arr, int end) {
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = arr.length -1;

    while (lo <= hi) {
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;

        if (arr[mid] == end && arr[mid+1] > end)
            return mid;

        if (mid <= end)
            lo = mid + 1;
        else
            hi = mid - 1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```